# PublishOn not firing when I delete input content

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-postbox

I am using knockout-postbox to mark dirty flag. The code looks like this:

```js
var ProfileModel = function() {
    this.nickName = ko.observable("name1").publishOn("dirty", true);
    this.emailAddress = ko.observable("email1").publishOn("dirty", true);
};

ko.postbox.subscribe("dirty", function(newValue) {
    // enable Save button
}, this);
```

nickName and emailAddress are tied to input boxes.

```html
<div id="profile">
    <input data-bind="value: nickName" /> </label>
    <input data-bind="value: emailAddress" /></label>
</div>
```

Steps to recreate the problem:

1. User goes to nickName input box and delete the content. `dirty` is raised and Save button is enabled.
2. User clicks Save button. The change is saved and the Save button becomes disabled.
3. User goes to emailAddress and delete the content. `dirty` is NOT raised somehow. User cannot save the change.
4. User types something on emailAddress or nickName. `dirty` is raised and Save button is enabled.

You can check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbw6a6qu/2/) to see it in action. There is no Save button in the jsfiddle example, but just try deleting the content of nickName and then emailAddress. You will see deleting the emailAddress does not raise `dirty` event.

Is this known bug in knockout-postbox? Is there better way to check dirtyness in knockout?

Comment: Yes I see the issue - I suspect it is a bug in postbox. I don't use postbox in that way so can't help. For edit/save/cancel have a look at https://github.com/stevegreatrex/ko.plus - a good edit/cancel/commit capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `publishOn` functionality of `knockout-postbox` will not publish the latest value again. In your example, you are publishing an empty string for "dirty" (empty nick name) and then an empty string again (empty email).

`publishOn` does support passing in your own equality comparer. In your case, you could pass in a function that always returns `false`.

For example, something like:

```
var alwaysPublish = function() { return false; }

var ProfileModel = function() {
    this.nickName = ko.observable("Ryan").publishOn("dirty", true, alwaysPublish);
    this.emailAddress = ko.observable("ryan@knockmeout.net").publishOn("dirty", true, alwaysPublish);
    this.log = ko.observableArray();
};
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qmbwhk8a/

You can also globally override the compare function by setting `ko.postbox.defaultComparer`.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you! One question though: wouldn't it be more intuitive to suppress duplicate values from the same source, rather than suppressing duplicate values to the same target, since `publishOn` is attached to the source?

Comment: @kennethc - yes, I might look a little closer at one changes would need to be made. The value is cached at the topic level, so that is what it is getting compared against. I think though that you have a totally valid use case that  the lib does not handle intuitively.